# Simple PHP web service is not returning error message

Tags: php, web-services, rest

i am using below code for checking user login system by web services. all is ok when i used correct information in url but soon i used wrong it does not return me the error.

code:

```
function service_response($api_response){

   $http_response_code = array(
        200 => 'OK',
        400 => 'Bad Request',
        401 => 'Unauthorized',
        403 => 'Forbidden',
        404 => 'Not Found'
    );

    header('HTTP/1.1 '.$api_response['status'].' '.$http_response_code[ $api_response['status'] ]);
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $json_response = json_encode($api_response);
    echo $json_response;
    exit;
}

$api_response_code = array(
    0 => array('HTTP Response' => 400, 'Message' => 'Unknown Error'),
    1 => array('HTTP Response' => 200, 'Message' => 'Success'),
    2 => array('HTTP Response' => 403, 'Message' => 'HTTPS Required'),
    3 => array('HTTP Response' => 401, 'Message' => 'Authentication Required'),
    4 => array('HTTP Response' => 401, 'Message' => 'Authentication Failed'),
    5 => array('HTTP Response' => 404, 'Message' => 'Invalid Request'),
    6 => array('HTTP Response' => 400, 'Message' => 'Invalid Response Format')
);


if( isset($_GET['actionid']) && $_GET['actionid'] == 'login_user'){
    $email    = $_GET['email'];
    $password = $_GET['password'];
    $query    = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE email = '".$email."' AND password = '".md5($password)."'");
    $data     = array();
        if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0) { 
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
    $response['code']               = 1;
    $response['status']             = $api_response_code[$response['code']]['HTTP Response'];
    $response['response_message']   = $api_response_code[$response['code']]['Message'];
    $response['message']            = 'You are logged In successfully';
    $response['data']               = $data;
    service_response($response);    

        }else{

    $response['code']               = 0;
    $response['status']             = $api_response_code[$response['code']]['HTTP Response'];
    $response['response_message']   = $api_response_code[$response['code']]['Message'];
    $response['message']            = 'Please enter correct email address and password';
    $response['data']               = $data;
    service_response($response);
    }
}
```

return correct information:

```
{"code":1,"status":200,"response_message":"Success","message":"You are logged In successfully","data":[{"user_id":"72"}]}
```

But when i put wrong details in my url it returns:

```
Bad Request
```

while i want this: `{"code":0,"status":404,"data":null}`

url with correct info: `http://xxxxxx/actions.php?actionid=login_user&email=mohsin@balianti.com&password=mohsin`

url with wrong info: `http://xxxxxx/actions.php?actionid=login_user&email=mohsin@balianti.com&password=ddfsdfdsf`

can somebody please help me..

thank you all

Comment: no one for the help??

Comment: It only 5 minutes since you opened the question?

Comment: Sorry mate. mostly people starts posting answers.

Comment: Can you show us the code that handles the service reply? (it must be equipped to deal with non-200 status codes).

Comment: What is the error in the `error.log`?

Comment: $api_response_code = array(
    0 => array('HTTP Response' => 400, 'Message' => 'Unknown Error'),
    1 => array('HTTP Response' => 200, 'Message' => 'Success'),
    2 => array('HTTP Response' => 403, 'Message' => 'HTTPS Required'),
    3 => array('HTTP Response' => 401, 'Message' => 'Authentication Required'),
    4 => array('HTTP Response' => 401, 'Message' => 'Authentication Failed'),
    5 => array('HTTP Response' => 404, 'Message' => 'Invalid Request'),
    6 => array('HTTP Response' => 400, 'Message' => 'Invalid Response Format')
);

Comment: i want {"code":0,"status":404,"data":null} rather than 404 Bad Request

Comment: @DanFromGermany your code works for me. thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `else { }` block you defined:

```
$response['code']               = 0;
```

This you are mapping to

```
0 => array('HTTP Response' => 400, 'Message' => 'Unknown Error'),
```

and 400 is mapped to

```
400 => 'Bad Request',
```

Proving your script works, wow!

If you want to change this, change your mappings:

```
$response['code']               = 3; // or 4 or whatever you define
```

Comment: can we talk some personal in PM on other email? i want to discuss something from you concerning with your country. please can you help me? if you are really from germany. sorry if it hurts

Comment: i will contact you personally wia stackoverflow. sorry again talking this on such forum

Comment: take it easy first. i am about to come in your country for MS program and want to ask you something regarding this. so take it easy and just relax. there are thousands of people live there in germany not you alone whom help me. right.? so be easy now. i did not meant to say anthing